# How to use order by and Limit in Spring Data JPA using QueryDSL

Tags: java, database, querydsl, spring-data

I am using Spring Data JPA with a RDBMS in my project. I have a requirement where I have to fetch a single record from the Database from a table which has the latest date. For this I need to use a limit and order by function OR using sub queries. However, I wished to know if i wish for not to use NamedQuery is there a way I can achieve this using Spring Data JPA and QueryDSL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shouldn't `QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)` do the trick for you? You could hand in a `new PageRequest(0, limit)` and thus would get back the first `limit`results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did actually find it. It returns a list but works just fine.

Comment: @Olver Gierke The only issue is it runs an unnecessary query to get the count. I just use QueryDSL in these cases, but a LimitOne syntax would be cool. Posted the suggestion [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-82?focusedCommentId=78956&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-78956)

Comment: It does not if you have a return type of `List` instead of `Page`.

Comment: In Case of QueryDslJpaRepository there is only one method and it always runs a count query. Is there another workaround to this? @OliverGierke

Comment: How about the sort order ? `QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)` does not include sort order.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the MIN and MAX function to attain this.

```
SELECT MAX(objDate) FROM Object
```

Comment: I was hoping not to use any named queries. By using Names query it is very simple but i was wondering if there was a way around this.