# spring data jpa query to limit

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I have query as such :

```
@Query("select a from Ability a where a.eventLogic = ?1 AND a.abilitySetId = ?2 ORDER BY    RAND() LIMIT ?3")
```

BUt i get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 117
```

How can i programmatically put in the limit number?

Comment: Can you post the code where you execute the query?

Comment: im using spring data jpa, so i have an interface as above.. i wonder if i could send in a pageable object??

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356322/how-to-use-order-by-and-limit-in-spring-data-jpa-using-querydsl

Comment: spring data jpa, has documentation, that states how to solve this using some paging. Thats what i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring data jpa, has documentation, that states how to solve this using some paging. Thats what i used

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and adding an explicit ASC clause solved it.